# Graph loop not terminating

Tags: c++

This is the representation of an adjacency list.When i try to print the graph the loop does not terminate and keeps repeating weird values again and again.What is wrong in the loops

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

class Graph{
    int V;
    list<int> *l;
public:
    Graph(int v){
        V=v;
        l=new list<int>[V];//Array of linked lists
    }
    void addEdge(int u,int v, bool bidirec=true){
        l[u].push_back(v);
        if(bidirec){//condition for bidirectional graph
            l[v].push_back(u);
        }
    }

    void printAdjList(){
        for(int i=0;i<V;i++){
                cout<<i<<"-->";
            for(int vertex:l[i]){//For each loop
                cout<<vertex<<",";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Graph g(5);//graph with 5 vertices
    g.addEdge(0,1);//adding edges
    g.addEdge(0,4);
    g.addEdge(4,3);
    g.addEdge(1,4);
    g.addEdge(1,2);
    g.addEdge(2,3);
    g.printAdjList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I run it.

Comment: What was the output? Did it start off as you expected? Does it always go wrong at the same point? What happened when you stepped through in a debugger?

Comment: in the online ide its working fine but in codeblocks ide it starts off from 0 and keeps adding edges infinitely

Comment: Are you compiling this *exact* code when you try it with codeblocks? Is this a copy/paste of what you are running?

Comment: unrelated: You've a memory leak because of the new with no delete...

Comment: why `list<int> *l;` instead of `std::vector<std::list<int>> l;` ? As-is, you don't `delete[] l;` and a vector would do that for you.

Comment: Given that you can use STL containers, you don't really have to define a special type for graphs. IMHO (and as others have commented) a `vector<vector<int>> AdjList` should be enough to have a adjacency list representation. The vector contains a adjacency list of every node. Example: AdjList[0] should have a vector of `{1,4}`, `AdjList[1] = {0, 4, 2}`, (assuming the graph is undirected) and so on. I have tried this, and it made things easier to manage.

Comment: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EG7mMQkQcZ4tBg9q) with `vector` instead of a C array and some other changes. Runs fine.